# Maven is pulling in the wrong dependency in one workspace

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am working on a a maven project with the following POM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.jbhunt</groupId>
<artifactId>ws-infrastructure-annotations</artifactId>
<version>LOCAL-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ws-infrastructure-annotations</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>Service to allow front-ends to upload any kind of file, publish upload events, and allow file query/retrieval</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <mockito-version>5.1.1</mockito-version>
    <netty.version>4.1.101.Final</netty.version>
    <log4j.version>2.20.0</log4j.version>
    <jackson.version>2.15.3</jackson.version>
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2022.0.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
            <version>${netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
            <version>3.37.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>9.43.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SQL Server, JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jbhunt.drive</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib-drive-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jbhunt</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib-infrastructure-annotations-dto</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Keycloak -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
        <version>22.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Kubernetes Config Maps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Rest Documentation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Azure Blob Storage -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>12.25.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Tika for Mime Type / Extensions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.prettytime</groupId>
        <artifactId>prettytime</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security/OAuth2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jbhunt</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib_infrastructure_requestMetric</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!--Used to check for log4j exploit-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ban-bad-log4j-versions</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <bannedDependencies>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:(,2.17.0)</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:(,2.17.0)</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:(,2.17.0)</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </bannedDependencies>
                        </rules>
                        <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

According to [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/3.1.4) `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 3.14` should have `spring-data-jpa 3.14` as a dependency but my IntelliJ Dependency Analyzer and running the command `mvn dependency:tree` shows it bringing in v 3.0.8.[image]
[image]

I have another project on my computer which pulls in the correct dependency so I assume the issue is something I am doing wrong in the pom file. I deleted the .m2 folder and rebuilt it and I get the same results. I know I can force the correct version with `<dependancyManagement>` but this issue is happening in several places so I would prefer to know what I am doing to cause this issue.

EDIT:

Based on the comments below I updated to 3.1.6 and removed all of the spring-boot manual version declarations. Going to 3.2 breaks the service and since my task is to update from SB 2 to SB3 of an existing service it is not worth the time to figure out why 3.2 breaks the service when 3.1.6 does not.

I still have the issue of spring-data-jpa 3.0.8 being pulled in. It appears the issue is a conflict with `spring-cloud-starter-parent`. Removing it fixes the dependency issue but it breaks the service so that is not an option. 2022.0.4 is the latest version of `spring-cloud-starter-parent` so I guess I will have to live with the lower versions (it happens for lots of dependencies). If one of the lower dependencies causes an issue I can fix it manually in `<dependencyManagement>`. If there is a better solution I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Why have you defined so many dependencies manually with versions instead of using the ones provided by SB... also the question why not using the most recent version of 3.1.X (3.1.6) or even 3.2.0... ?  Also defining things like mockito which is is an old version (5.8.0) using mockito-inline which is not neccesary anymore etc.. ?

Comment: Agree 100% with the comment above. What about starting clean with a new pom.xml from [https://start.spring.io/](https://start.spring.io/) and then adding one by one just the dependencies you need (without version each time it is managed by Boot)?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. My task is to update from SB 2 to SB 3 and I don't have time to start from scratch. I did incorporate some of you ideas and found the issue, although I don't have a great solution. See the Edit on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud version to use with Boot `3.2` is `2023.0.0`, and it was released earlier today, maybe 20h before you wrote your question.

Before that, the `2023.0.0-RC1` version was compatible with boot `3.2` (and `https://start.spring.io` was setting this Cloud version when you chose a Cloud dependency with Boot `3.2`).